# Azure DevOps FileTransform task variables in yaml

Tags: azure-devops, deployment, yaml

I have a problem using Azure DevOps FileTransform@1 task in my pipeline to substitute variables in json file. Nothing is done.
My yaml is:

```
variables:
  - name: MyVariable
    value: TheValue
steps:
  - task:FileTransform@1
    inputs:
      folderPath: ./**.zip
      fileType: json
      targetFiles: '**/appsettings.*.json'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the variables declarations:
Use

```
variables:
  MyVariable: TheValue
```

Instead of:

```
variables:
  - name: MyVariable
    value: TheValue
```

In the second form, you define a list of variables and not an object like in first form. The task FileTransform is unable to get the name of the variables from a list to substitute in json file.
I was using the list form to create variable with conditional value:

```
variables:
  - group: AWS   
  - name: AWS_AccessKey
    ${{ if eq(parameters['DeployEnvironment'], 'Development') }}:
      value: $(AWS_ACCESSKEY.Development)
    ${{ if eq(parameters['DeployEnvironment'], 'PreProd') }}:
      value: $(AWS_ACCESSKEY.PreProd)
    ${{ if eq(parameters['DeployEnvironment'], 'Production') }}:
      value: $(AWS_ACCESSKEY.Production)
```

I didn't find how to use the "object" form for variables and use condition for values.